# input field gives advice, automaticly?

Tags: html, validation, custom-data-attribute, html-input

I stumbled on the HTML5 checkout-form for me.

[here can you see source](http://codepen.io/DavieB/pen/DonHl)

I started to change it, and I saw that if you enter the wrong email address, you will receive advice/tips. After reviewing the code, I have not found a java script. But I noticed that the INPUT includes non-standard attributes.

To test type "foo" for E-Mail then Enter

as

```
data-required
```

if you fork this project, u can check one more feature: open Browser, give correct e-mail and press Enter: 
so you get next url

```
...local.../index.html?email=mail%40test.de
```

Why?! How?!

I know the data - attribute, data its just for me, for js... but it seems that they have takes optional functionality. Or is chrome, understands that it is email, and gives tips?

I'm trying to understand, but still can not.

Thanks!

Comment: The secret is not `data-required` -- the secret is `type="email"`. That's what causes the tips to occur.

Comment: but who / what gives me advice? Browser - Chrome? Can it opera/Safari and others too?

Comment: Yep, it's chrome not javascript. You can try it in most browsers and it will do something similar.

Comment: oh, thx, i did not know

Comment: its html5 standard response. google html5 data-validation.

Comment: @soktinpk, please set your hint as answer the author accept the answer to remove the question from unanswered list

Comment: @mGouda Ok, thanks. I answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret is not `data-required` -- the secret is `type="email"`. That's what causes the tips to occur.

It's chrome not javascript. You can try it in most browsers and it will do something similar.

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Try entering an invalid email">
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Notice the `type="email"`. This tells google chrome that the input should be an email address and, when you submit, it automatically tells you if the email address is invalid.

Other types include `type="number"`, `type="date"`, etc.